# Max Disk Space an iPhone App Can Use

Tags: iphone

I have searched here and found the assertion that "no single application may occupy more than 2GB of hard disk space."

Not to question that statement, it seems a reasonable policy, but can anyone provide a reference to that policy in the Apple Docs. I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The policy (or reference) for the 2GB limit for an application that can be submitted to the App Store can be found under the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide PDF](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (page 57, section B under the Application section).

There is no reference or limitation of disk space once the application has been installed to the iPhone or iPod Touch device. The only limitation would be available disk space at time of writing.

Comment: Thank you Tammen.

Your first statement is accurate: the exact reference is "Zipped binaries ready for submission cannot be
larger than 2GB."

I still wonder about your second statement: "There is no reference or limitation of disk space once the application has been installed to the iPhone or iPod Touch device."

Is it Apple's policy that an app can expand until the available space (minus the 200 meg that Apple requires) is used up?

Thanks again for the reference.

Comment: Michael - I've not come across any reference or policy for a limitation of disk usage once the application has been installed on the users device. Also, I have not heard of any developers applications being rejected due to the fact that it creates/downloads additional data (large amounts) on the device. I believe that the only restriction would be available device memory.

Comment: I have an app that currently will use around 8 GB of storage (if the user selects all available data sets for offline use) and it works fine. The zipped binary is < 2 MB

Answer (score 5):

There is no maximum amount of space that your application can use.  You can eat up all of the available space on the device if you wish.

The space available can be found in by using the NSFileManager - specifically attributesOfFileSystemForPath

-t

Comment: But will APple approve an app that used all available space or does Apple have an approvable limit.

Comment: So the quoted statement in the question is just false?  Either way, I would appreciate a pointer back to something from Apple.

Comment: There is no limitation on the amount of space the installed application can use. Statements from Apple employees to this affect can be found on the forums in the iPhone Developer Area.

There is no statement in the Apple documentation to that effect, however there is nothing that limits your application from using all available disk space should you have a reason to do so.  

Apple will not block your application - though your users may not be thrilled about you consuming all available device space.

-t