# Can we import big size file into my app?

Tags: ios

Suppose my app size is 5MB and I am importing files from email or iTunes into my app.

Is there any specific memory size after which I can't import files to my app?

Comment: "into your app"?  You mean when it's running or during development (when building the app bundle)?

Comment: what do you mean? importing into ram? downloading to the device? then the limits are the ram in the particular device (1gig? 2gig?) or storage space (16gig, 32gig, etc...)

Comment: Or saving  file in the documents folder or having it al in memory? Also what do you mean by: "app size is 5MB"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max Disk Space an iPhone App Can Use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897034/max-disk-space-an-iphone-app-can-use)

Comment: Why are you downvoting this? It's a perfectly valid question to ask.

Comment: There is only a limit to the size of an app that can be uploaded to the AppStore (which is 2GB). However, the increase of space on a device is only limited by the capacity of the device.

Comment: Not down voter but the question is lacking sufficient information to understand what is being asked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897034/max-disk-space-an-iphone-app-can-use

Answer (score 0):

No, you are effectively only constrained by the storage capacity of the device. If it runs out, you won't be able to add any content to your app any more either.

Comment: You mean "storage capacity", not "memory".

Comment: Or RAM memory if reading a file into an `NSData` for instance.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant storage capacity, not memory! I updated the answer.