# How large is AsyncStorage in React Native?

Tags: react-native

The documentation says it should be used instead of LocalStorage, but it doesn't list anything regarding how large it is. If I recall, LocalStorage in web browsers is only about 10mb.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It writes to disk and is very large if there is free space. On iOS there are no artificial caps other than what the underlying operating system imposes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1897383/454967.

Comment: One thing to note is that as of 0.12, Android will only have 6MB of storage as per this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3387#issuecomment-148042923

Answer (score 15):

The new way of increasing AsyncStorage size on react-native is to add `AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB=` property to your `android/gradle.properties` as shown here: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size/

Comment: the new link: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size

Answer (score 3):

#### This is an old answer, the new method is mentioned in justin answer above..

---

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991073/react-native-async-storage-limit-on-android), to increase the **6mb** limit on Android.. try this:

in `MainApplication.java` add these lines in `onCreate` function

```
  public void onCreate() {
    // ...
    long size = 50L * 1024L * 1024L; // 50 MB
    com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setMaximumSize(size);
  }
```

Comment: Any upper limit for this?

Answer (score 2):

On Android the limit is 6mb by default. Check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/ReactDatabaseSupplier.java#L46).

But you can increase that limit calling the method [setMaximumSize](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/ReactDatabaseSupplier.java#L142).