# React native Async Storage Limit on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a React Native app which will easily exceed the 6mb limit.
According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/ReactDatabaseSupplier.java#L144), I should be able to use the method setMaximumSize, however I'm not sure of where or how I should invoke it in my project.

A practical example would be welcome.

EDIT: For anyone who needs this in the future here's how you do it:

```
    // MainApplication.getPackages()
long size = 50L * 1024L * 1024L; // 50 MB
com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setMaximumSize(size);
```

Comment: why do you exceed the limit?

Comment: @bzlies where do you put this code? in `getPackages()` inside the function before you return the array?

Answer (score 2):

Try the new way as mentioned [in the documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size) :

Add a `AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB` property to your `android/gradle.properties`:

```
AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB=10
```

Now you can define the new size in MB. In this example, the new limit is 10 MB.