# Determine React Native Async Storage Space Used

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

Is there anyway to determine how much AsyncStorage my app has used and is currently available?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3387 I am not sure if there is actually a way to get it. However Android has a [6mb](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/ReactDatabaseSupplier.java#L46) limit, iOS there is no limit other than the amount of space that is allowed for the app (currently storage per app is capped at 2GB) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875726/how-large-is-asyncstorage-in-react-native.