# console.error: Error storing the data in react native in android device

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

[image]I'm developing a React Native app, whenever I store a large set of data in Redux Persist I'm getting the error:

`Error storing the data in android`

So I am increasing the storing limit as per few answers provided in few sites, in  `mainApplication.java`, but this is not solving my problem,

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    long size = 900L * 1024L * 1024L; 
    com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setMaximumSize(size);
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please use proper formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875726/how-large-is-asyncstorage-in-react-native) help?

Comment: @jeevitha aiyappa please share the code you used to get to the point you're at now