# What is the maximum size for redux persist?

Tags: database, react-native, redux, storage, redux-persist

I have a medium sized objects thats maximum size is 10mb .

**What is the maximum size to store and persist data in redux using redux-persist ?**

Also, What is the best approach for such sized data , to use redux-persist or use a database like realm ?

Answer (score 4):

## Update

When this post was originally written it was not possible to set the size of `AsyncStorage`. However in May 2019 the following [commit](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/commit/608e2d80cd4a8aa3dbb2f7c08fb317ce4a180344#diff-87e8e3ff9b07f1dec8fe4ce54a532d40b7acce612c527b4a7cec2b18fed39299) changed that.

You can read more about it [here](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size)

> Current Async Storage's size is set to 6MB. Going over this limit causes database or disk is full error. This 6MB limit is a sane limit to protect the user from the app storing too much data in the database. This also protects the database from filling up the disk cache and becoming malformed (endTransaction() calls will throw an exception, not rollback, and leave the db malformed). You have to be aware of that risk when increasing the database size. We recommend to ensure that your app does not write more data to AsyncStorage than space is left on disk. Since AsyncStorage is based on SQLite on Android you also have to be aware of the SQLite limits.

If you still wish to increase the storage capability the you can add the following to your `android/gradle.properties`

`AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB=10`

This will set the size of to **10MB** instead of the default **6MB**.

## Original Answer

If you use the default storage settings for `redux-persist` in `react-native` it will use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/src/storage/index.native.js)

`AsyncStorage` has some limitations in the amount it can store depending on the operating system that you are using.

In Android if we look at [native code](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/blob/044a2aae03292011397f3461b9bd7c55c43897e1/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/ReactDatabaseSupplier.java#L46) behind `AsyncStorage` we can see that the upper limit is just **6MB**

In iOS there are no such limits on the amount of storage that can be used. You can see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897034/max-disk-space-an-iphone-app-can-use/1897383#1897383) for a further discussion.

If you don't want to use `AsnycStorage` there are alternatives like `redux-persist-fs-storage` or `redux-persist-filesystem-storage` which get around the **6MB** limitation on Android.

Comment: This updated answer of changing  the db size in gradle.properties does not work, at least in my experience. I believe  the reason is because this only changes the max size of the total storage space, but per key limit still remains 6MB. Since redux-persist stores the data under a since key, it cannot get around the 6MB limit.

Comment: @JustinLok this is a bit old but were you able to fix this?